# Incorrect dynamic indexing of mat4 in vertex shader on Adreno 3xx

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

I have a shader that dynamically indexes uniform data, based on a vertex stream. It uses the following shader:

```
#version 300 es
uniform mat4 data[24];
attribute vec4 pos;
attribute float index;
void main() 
{
    gl_Position = (pos) * ( data[int(index * 1.01)]);
}
```

When run on any Adreno 300 series Android GPU, the `data` is not indexed correctly. It is sometimes correct, but frequently, the geometry seems to be accessing bogus uniform data, causing missing geometry, or corrupted rendering. The exact same code run on other Android devices (even Adreno 200 series) produces correct results. When captured with the Adreno profiler, the rendered result also shows correctly. Further, a shader which is essentially equivalent:

```
#version 300 es
uniform vec4 data[96];
attribute vec4 pos;
attribute float index;
void main() 
{
    gl_Position.x = dot(pos, data[int(index * 4.01 + 0.0)]);
    gl_Position.y = dot(pos, data[int(index * 4.01 + 1.0)]);
    gl_Position.z = dot(pos, data[int(index * 4.01 + 2.0)]);
    gl_Position.w = dot(pos, data[int(index * 4.01 + 3.0)]);
}
```

Produces correct results (with modified `glUniform` code). Is this a bug in the Adreno 300 series driver dynamically indexing `mat4` data, is there something incorrect about my shader code, or is there something non-standard/incorrect here that the Adreno 300 doesn't support?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting `mediump` precision (default is `highp`)? Implementations of GPU's internal MAD instructions can have different bugs with different precisions.

Comment: @keaukraine I haven't tried, but, it seems like a potential minefield if `mad` is not consistent across GPUs using different precisions (do you have a reference for this?). For example, how would I then know if setting it to `mediump` is not breaking the function on another GPU?